Se, Sp, NPV and PPV questions for repeated measures data
I have a dataset that contains multiple test results (expressed as %) per participant, at various time points post kidney transplant. The dataset also contains the rejection group the participant belongs to, which is fixed per participant, i.e. does not vary across timepoints(rej_group=0 if they didn't have allograft rejection, or 1 if they did have it).
The idea is that this test, which is a blood test, has the potential to be a more non-invasive biomarker of allograft rejection (can discriminate rejection from non-rejection groups), as opposed to biopsy. Research has shown that usually participants who express levels of this test>1% have a higher likelihood of allograft rejection than those with levels under 1%. What I'm interested in doing for the time being is something that should be relatively quick and straightforward: I want to show in a table the sensitivity, specificity, NPV, and PPV for the 1%, and 0.5% test thresholds that discriminate rejection from no rejection.
What I'm struggling with is, I don't know if I need to use a method that accounts for repeated measures (my outcome is fixed for each participant across time points, but test results are not), or maybe just summarize the test results per participant and leave it there.
What I've done so far is displayed below for the 1% level only (using a made up dummy dataset that has the same structure as my original data). I did both scenarios: in the first scenario, I basically summarized participant level data by taking the median of the test results to account for the repeated measures on the test, and then categorized based on median_result>1%, and finally computed the Se, Sp, NPV and PPV but I'm really unsure whether this is the correct way to do it or not.
In the second scenario, I fit a GEE model to account for the correlation among measurements within subjects (though not sure if I need to given that my outcome is fixed for each participant?) and then used the predicted probabilities from the GEE and then used those in  in PROC LOGISTIC to do the ROC analysis, and finally computed Se, Sp, PPV and NPV.
Scenario 1:
input id $ transdt:mmddyy. rej_group date:mmddyy. result;
format transdt mmddyy10. date mmddyy10.;
datalines;
1   8/26/2009   0   10/4/2019   0.15
1   8/26/2009   0   12/9/2019   0.49
1   8/26/2009   0   3/16/2020   0.41
1   8/26/2009   0   7/10/2020   0.18
1   8/26/2009   0   10/26/2020  1.2
1   8/26/2009   0   4/12/2021   0.2
1   8/26/2009   0   10/11/2021  0.17
1   8/26/2009   0   1/31/2022   0.76
1   8/26/2009   0   8/29/2022   0.12
1   8/26/2009   0   11/28/2022  1.33
1   8/26/2009   0   2/27/2023   1.19
1   8/26/2009   0   5/15/2023   0.16
1   8/26/2009   0   9/25/2023   0.65
2   2/15/2022   0   9/22/2022   1.32
2   2/15/2022   0   3/23/2023   1.38
3   3/25/2021   1   10/6/2021   3.5
3   3/25/2021   1   3/22/2022   0.18
3   3/25/2021   1   10/13/2022  1.90
3   3/25/2021   1   3/30/2023   0.23
4   7/5/2018    0   8/29/2019   0.15
4   7/5/2018    0   3/2/2020    0.12
4   7/5/2018    0   6/19/2020   6.14
4   7/5/2018    0   9/22/2020   0.12
4   7/5/2018    0   10/12/2020  0.12
4   7/5/2018    0   4/12/2021   0.29
5   8/19/2018   1   6/17/2019   0.15
6   1/10/2019   1   4/29/2019   1.58
6   1/10/2019   1   9/9/2019    1.15
6   1/10/2019   1   5/2/2020    0.85
6   1/10/2019   1   8/3/2020    0.21
6   1/10/2019   1   8/16/2021   0.15
6   1/10/2019   1   3/2/2022    0.3
7   7/16/2018   0   8/24/2021   0.28
7   7/16/2018   0   11/2/2021   0.29
7   7/16/2018   0   5/24/2022   2.27
7   7/16/2018   0   10/6/2022   0.45
8   4/3/2019    1   9/24/2020   1.06
8   4/3/2019    1   10/20/2020  0.51
8   4/3/2019    1   1/21/2021   0.39
8   4/3/2019    1   3/25/2021   2.44
8   4/3/2019    1   7/2/2021    0.59
8   4/3/2019    1   9/28/2021   5.54
8   4/3/2019    1   1/5/2022    0.62
8   4/3/2019    1   1/9/2023    1.43
8   4/3/2019    1   4/25/2023   1.41
8   4/3/2019    1   8/3/2023    1.13
9   3/12/2020   1   8/27/2020   0.49
9   3/12/2020   1   10/27/2020  0.29
9   3/12/2020   1   4/16/2021   0.12
9   3/12/2020   1   5/10/2021   0.31
9   3/12/2020   1   9/20/2021   0.31
9   3/12/2020   1   2/26/2022   0.24
9   3/12/2020   1   6/13/2022   0.92
9   3/12/2020   1   12/5/2022   2.34
9   3/12/2020   1   7/3/2023    2.21
10  10/10/2019  0   12/12/2019  0.29
10  10/10/2019  0   1/24/2020   0.32
10  10/10/2019  0   3/3/2020    0.28
10  10/10/2019  0   7/2/2020    0.24
;
run;
proc print data=test; run;

/* Create binary indicator for cfDNA > 1% */
data binary_grouping;
    set test;
    cfDNA_above=(result>1);         /* 1 if cfDNA > 1%, 0 otherwise */
run;
proc freq data=binary_grouping; tables cfDNA_above*rej_group; run;

proc sql;
    create table participant_level as
    select id, rej_group, median(result) as median_result
    from binary_grouping
    group by id, rej_group;
quit;
proc print data=participant_level; run;

data cfDNA_classified;
    set participant_level;
    cfDNA_class = (median_result >1); /* Positive test if median cfDNA > 1% */
run;

proc freq data=cfDNA_classified;
    tables cfDNA_class*rej_group/ nocol nopercent sparse out=confusion_matrix;
run;


data metrics;
    set confusion_matrix;
    if cfDNA_class=1 and rej_group=1 then TP = COUNT; /* True Positives */
    if cfDNA_class=0 and rej_group=1 then FN = COUNT; /* False Negatives */
    if cfDNA_class=0 and rej_group=0 then TN = COUNT; /* True Negatives */
    if cfDNA_class=1 and rej_group=0 then FP = COUNT; /* False Positives */
run;
proc print data=metrics; run;

proc sql;
    select 
        sum(TP)/(sum(TP)+sum(FN)) as Sensitivity,
        sum(TN)/(sum(TN)+sum(FP)) as Specificity,
        sum(TP)/(sum(TP)+sum(FP)) as PPV,
        sum(TN)/(sum(TN)+sum(FN)) as NPV
    from metrics;
quit;

Scenario 2:
class id rej_group;
model rej_group(event='1')=result / dist=b;
repeated subject=id;
effectplot / ilink;
estimate '@1%' intercept 1 result 1 / ilink cl;
output out=gout p=p;
run;
proc logistic data=gout rocoptions(id=id);
id result;
model rej_group(event='1')= / nofit outroc=or;
roc 'GEE model' pred=p;
run;

I would greatly appreciate people's input/thoughts on this.
Thanks!

Some comments based on looking at the "dummy dataset". Some patients have only 1 datapoint, others over 10. Some patient's first datapoint is 10 years after the transplant; surely you should know if there is rejection. For pretty much all patients, some of the measurements are above, and others below the proposed thresholds.  I would guess that if this test were to be adopted clinically, it would not require repeated measurements every 6-8 months (as seems to be the case in the dataset). This may be due to the data being "dummied", but it raises questions. Clarifications much appreciated.

Thanks for your response! Yes, even the real data is a bit odd in the sense that it's highly unbalanced. For example, some participants have only a few observations, while others have a lot; some have their first test many years after transplant, etc. However, one of the requirements of the study was for participants to have their cfDNA tests every 6 months (+/-2 months). For now, investigators's just interested in seeing a table of Se, Sp, NPV, PPV for two levels of cfDNA's (1% and 0.5%) ability to discriminate rejection from no rejection (cfDNA>1% considered positive result). Hope this helps

Thanks for the clarifications. This still leaves my last point. Take "dummy patient" #3; he/she yo-yo's every ~6 months between way above your thresholds, and way below. Patient #4 is well below the threshold, except for 1 measurement which is >6. Is that because of the "dummy data", or does teh real data show that much variability?

My actual dataset has 780 observations, for which the mean (STD) test result=0.7 (1.7), median = 0.3, min=0.04 and max=14. So, there are some outliers for sure. But for example, of the 780 observations, only 90 observations have results>1. The mean (STD) of the test results for these 90 observations is 4 (3.6), median=2.7, min=1.1, and max=14. Hope this helps. Am I correct in using GEE and then PROC logistic on the predicted probs from GEE, or is that not needed given the rejection status is fixed, and I should just summarize the test results instead?

Because your data is so disparate, and varies quite a nbit over time, in a first pass, I would not worry about any correlation. I would instead compute Se, Sp, etc., at each time point (against your 2 thresholds);  at 6 months (+/-2), 12, etc. That would exclude from some of these calculatins the subjects for which such data is missing. Do this for all time points which make clinical sense.  See how consistent the test is over time. You may also see if distinction between accute and chronic rejection makes sense (the test may work better for 1 or the other?).

That makes sense, thanks for your suggestions! :)
